# Match the folder list by using regex in python

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

How to match the following case in python regex,

```
str = "https://10.0.4.3/myrepos/Projects/ID87_070_138"
```

I need to match "ID87_070_138" this type of folders from the list of folders.

```
The pattern is "ID<number>_<number>_<Number>".
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ID\d+_\d+_\d+
```

Matches the `ID` followed by three groups of *one* or *more* digits, separated by underscore.

And the Python code:

```
> import re
> str = "https://10.0.4.3/myrepos/Projects/ID87_070_138"
> print re.findall(r"ID\d+_\d+_\d+", str)
```

With the result:

```
['ID87_070_138']
```